# How to set up an optimization problem for grouping things?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

I am trying to group items into bundles. There is a list of items, each at a different price. The bundle price has to be at least 1000, but anything beyond should be considered loss. I thought I can do this by hand, but there has to be a more optimal way to do this through calculus optimization.

Objective, put the following items into a bundle, each item can be selected once:
$$\begin{array}{|c|} 
 & \text{Price}  \\ \hline
\text{A} & 826  \\ \hline
\text{B} & 1152\\ \hline
\text{C} & 383\\ \hline
\text{D} & 563\\ \hline
\text{E} & 457\\ \hline
\text{F} & 279\\ \hline
\text{G} & 294\\ \hline
\text{H} & 896\\ \hline
\text{I} & 319\\ \hline
\text{J} & 295\\ \hline
\text{K} & 255\\ \hline
\text{L} & 321\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Loss: Anything beyond 1000 per bundle

(I have a basic familiarity with optimization problem and basic software like the cvxpy python library, so the issue for me is how to set up an objective and loss function for combinatorial problems like these.)

Comment: This looks like a variation on the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), I would start there.

Comment: If your only objective is to minimize the loss (which you've said is the sum of the bundle amounts in excess of 1000, then you could simply put each item into its own bundle.  Are you sure you're not leaving something out of the problem statement?

Comment: A good start is to let binary decision variable $x_{i,b}$ indicate whether item $i$ appears in bundle $b$ and nonnegative slack and surplus variables to measure the error for each bundle.

Comment: @BrianBorchers bundle has to be at least $1000, but anything beyond should be considered a loss. I updated the wording.

Comment: @RobPratt What would this loss function look like? It also seems that the decision variable has to be a function of a previous iterations of the problem since you can only know if you have allocated an item by looking at past allocation (?)

Comment: Add all the prices, divide by $1000$ and the quotient gives you the max number of bundles you can make so each bundle adds to at least $1000$. The remainder gives you the loss. Now you know the number of bundles to make so each is min $1000$ and all combinations will add to the same loss.

Comment: The loss only increases if you make less number of bundles than the max no. of bundles (let's call optimal number of bundles) we calculated.

Comment: @MathLover the quotient is an upper bound but is not achievable in this case.

Comment: @RobPratt I would not add $1152$ to it as it is a separate bundle. Rest adds to $4888$ so $4$ bundles. If we make total of $5$ bundles, the loss in this case will be $888 + 152$.

Comment: @MathLover Yes, that matches the optimal value I found for this case.  In general, the quotient is not necessarily achievable even if all items are $\le 1000$.  For example, suppose there are 10 items with price 999 each.  The quotient is 9, but the maximum achievable number of bundles is 5.

Comment: @RobPratt good point. I agree with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the new problem definition, you need only surplus variables but no slack variables.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_b s_b$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_b x_{i,b} &= 1&&\text{for $i\in I$} \tag1\\
\sum_i p_i x_{i,b} &= 1000 + s_b &&\text{for $b\in B$} \tag2\\
x_{i,b} &\in \{0,1\} &&\text{for $i\in I$, $b\in B$} \\
s_b &\ge 0 &&\text{for $b\in B$}
\end{align}
The number of bundles is bounded by $1$ and $\lfloor\sum_i p_i/1000\rfloor$.

Constraint $(1)$ assigns each item to exactly one bundle.
Constraint $(2)$ assigns at least $\$1000$ to each bundle and measures the surplus.

For your data, the optimal number of bundles turns out to be $5$, with minimum loss $1040$.